Shortcut W isn't working in sculpt mode
In sculpt mode when trying to open the tool brushes pie menu with the key W this error appears:
Tool 'builtin.select_box' not found for space 'VIEW_3D'.

I have loaded the factory settings and errors continue to occur.
I'm using Blender 4.2, how can I fix this issue?

That works fine here in 4.2 although I've not actually used it in anger yet. It's also working fine whether the toolbar is visible or not.

This happened to me. I noticed that the pie Menus and many other default addons are now not included by default, you have to download those using the Preference Menu.
The Preference Menu is inside the Edit Menu.
So, go to Edit > Preferences > Get Extensions (Blender will ask you for internet access)
Then , search "3D viewport Pie Menus", install that and now works and you will see the addon inside the addon area of the preferences.



Aha! Yes. I did download the pie menus extension when I installed 4.2 so that would be it! A better error message would help though!

@JohnEason Yes, you are right not a very good message. The fact that we have to download some "default " addons now is weird

Yes. That applies to the Loop tools, Mesh: Boolean and other Blender addons too!
